# Stickyback Velcro Application

Tags: ceiling

Adhesive-back Velcro is to be applied to a ceiling and a sensor bracket temporarily for a test.  When selecting the Velcro half to be attached to the ceiling, is there an advantage to using the ‘fuzzy’ strip or its counterpart to the ceiling?  Which strip should be attached to the ceiling and why?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When attaching velcro, my thought process is - when the two items are separated, which one would it be more pleasing to have the fuzzy side or the scratchy side?  Using velcro to mount a flashlight?  Fuzzy side on the flashlight for sure because it's soft.  Normally it ends up being scratchy side on the fixed surface and soft side on the portable piece.

You might also consider which side would pick up more dirt or dust when they are separated.  They both stick the same and have the same forces acting on them when attached, so my decisions focus on the separated items.

Comment: Having the "hook" or scratchy side on the torch in your pocket...pia  exactly, plus 1.